# Сложение переменных JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Имеется следующий код:

```
var automatopt = 231;
var automatprem = 370;
var automatec = 161;

avtomat = parseFloat(document.getElementById('avtomat').checked); 

if (document.getElementById('avtomat').checked) {
    cenaopt+automatopt;
    cenaprem+automatprem;
    cenaec+automatec;
} 

document.getElementById('cenaopt').innerHTML = cenaopt;
document.getElementById('cenaec').innerHTML = cenaec;
document.getElementById('cenaprem').innerHTML = cenaprem;
```

По идее, если выполняется условие, то три переменные cenaopt, cenaec, cenaprem, должны складываться со значениями automatopt, automatprem, automatec. Условие выполняется, это я проверял, а вот переменные отказываются складываться. В чём проблема? Как прибавить значения, исходя из выполнения условия?

Comment: А вы там результат сложения присвоить ни чему не забыли?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

При сложении вы не испольуете результата операции. Что-то мне подсказывает, что вместо `+` в должны использовать `+=`. Смысл этой операции как раз и заключается в увеличении переменной на значение правого операнда. Например:

```
var a = 3;
a += 4;
console.log(a);
```

выведет `7`. А еще оператор `+=` может быть выражен через `+` и `=`:

```
var a = 3, b = 3;
// Следующие две строки эквивалентны
a += 4;
b = b + 4;
```

Если говорить о вашем коде, то он должен выглядеть как-то так:

```
// ...
if (document.getElementById('avtomat').checked) {
    cenaopt += automatopt;
    cenaprem += automatprem;
    cenaec += automatec;
}
// ...
```

Comment: @Лёня Спасибо в рейтинг не положишь :) Пожалуйста, не забудьте отметить правильный ответ